# What can be stored in the bucket of hash table in C

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm new with hashing so I wondered if I have structure like below and I'm using hash function to may key to value, how can I store the third element number into the hash table?

I found a lot of implementations on github with key/value but I'm confused how to store another value it may not be hashed with key, a just need to store it.

```
struct my_struct
{

int key;

char value[512];

int number;

};
```

Comment: the first "thing" sounds like an `std::map` from C++, the second option sounds more like an SQL database.

Comment: You just make whatever you want stored in the hash a part of the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical hash-table implementation have a "table" (array) of the structures that are to be stored in the hash-table. Something like this

```
struct my_struct hash_table[SOME_SIZE];
```

Then you calculate the key and store it at position `key % SOME_SIZE` in the array. The extra data in the structures are filled in as usual.

To avoid collisions, each entry in the table is actually a linked list, so multiple keys that are stored in the same position in the table is a node in the list.